# Redirect to a file in the same folder with Razor c# and Web Pages

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-webpages

I am using the default routing with web pages..you can use things like /mypage/myfistparam/mysecondparam and it will end up at /mypage.cshtml with access to those paramters.

What I cant work out is how to redirect to a page in the same current directory so from mypage/param1;

```
Response.Redirect("newpage");
```

will redirect to /mypage/newpage. I can use the app relative ~;

```
Response.Redirect("~/newpage");
```

but that will redirect to /newpage (no good if I am in an unknown sub folder)

This should be simple but I guess its something to do with the default routing behaviour.

Any ideas..?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 Response.Redirect(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/newpage"));
```

or this (same result):

```
Response.Redirect(Href("~/newpage")); // note that works only in razor
```

**EDIT (misunderstanding)**

The best way that i can imagine is an extension method:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static void RedirectToSameDirectory(this HttpContextBase context, string fileName)
    {
        var builder = new UriBuilder(context.Request.Uri);
        builder.FileName = fileName;
        context.Response.Redirect(builder.Uri.ToString());
    }
}

// in razor
Context.RedirectToSameDirectory("filename");
```

Sorry in advance, probably something is wrong, i am not at my desk, but the idea is fine.